# Minimize console application

Tags: c#, window, console-application

Is it possible to minimize the console application from code without the use of DLL imports?

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("User32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow([In] IntPtr hWnd, [In] Int32 nCmdShow);
```

So far I only found solutions that require this and I wonder if it is impossible without it.

Comment: There is nothing like this implemented in `Windows Console-Applications`. That's the reason why you have to call the `Kernel32` and `User32` unmanaged dll's directly for achieving this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

Console applications, or any command line application that is run through the console, don't have enough access to the window hosting the console itself.
There's hardly any point in having this possibility for almost all instances where console application are used.

**In many cases such a window might not even exist.**

Think of a remote console session, the application is being executed on another machine, you only get the output sent to your console. How could the remote application possibly care about the window you are using? For what the remote application knows, "you" might be a script and there isn't even a window to start with.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes sense. It even answered some other doubts that I had about console input and output.

Answer (score 0):

As r41n already stated, No.

However, if your intention was to hide the console, and the application does not require any user input - you should be able to change the output type to Windows Application in the application settings. This will hide the console on startup

Comment: I have hybrid application that runs as WPF or console application according to way it was started. The console window is open even when it runs as WPF application. I need output to console and that would be difficult with the Windows Application as an output type.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Honestly would have just left this as a comment but I don't even have the rep to do so yet. Hope you are able to find a solution to your issue that suits your needs.